# Display background image if JavaScript disabled

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've got a div block that uses a [parallax scroller](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) to display parallax wallpaper:

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="whatever.jpg" id="MyElement">
    <!-- lots of nested HTML -->
</div>
```

I saw a neat trick for using `hidden` to hide a `div` when there is no JavaScript, but I don't want to hide all the nested blocks here. Is there a clean way to do this, other than setting the `class` to a simple wallpaper class then using `document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "parallax-window";` to override?

Answer (score 0):

try the `<noscript>` tag:

```
<noscript>
   <style>
         div{
            background-image: url("image.png");
         }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: I want the contents of the `div` to remain visible for both JavaScript present and not present; a simple `noscript` is not going to help me get there.

Comment: you may use style tag inside the noscript which gives you a lot of options